# Offline installing g++ on 10.04 lucid gives cyclic dependency

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

when i try to install offline g++-4.4 package it gives dependency on  libstdc++6-4.4-dev and  when i try to install libstdc++6-4.4-dev it gives dependency on  g++-4.4.

```
ocpe@blrkec241972d:~/Download/g++$ sudo dpkg -i g++-4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
    (Reading database ... 45040 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to replace g++-4.4 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 (using g++-4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement g++-4.4 ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++-4.4:
     g++-4.4 depends on libstdc++6-4.4-dev (= 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1); however:
      Package libstdc++6-4.4-dev is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing g++-4.4 (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for man-db ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     g++-4.4
    ocpe@blrkec241972d:~/Download/g++$ sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6-4.4-dev_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
    (Reading database ... 45040 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to replace libstdc++6-4.4-dev 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 (using libstdc++6-4.4-dev_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement libstdc++6-4.4-dev ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++6-4.4-dev:
     libstdc++6-4.4-dev depends on g++-4.4 (= 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1); however:
      Package g++-4.4 is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing libstdc++6-4.4-dev (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     libstdc++6-4.4-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing them simultaneously:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb
```

Comment: not working.
does not shows any error. but when i try to get the g++ version through `$g++ -v` it shows nothing.
here it is:

Comment: `ocpe@blrkec241972d:~/Download/g++$ sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb
(Reading database ... 45040 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace g++-4.4 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 (using .../g++-4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement g++-4.4 ...
Preparing to replace libstdc++6 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 (using .../libstdc++6_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libstdc++6 ...
Preparing to replace libstdc++6-4.4-dev 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 (using .../libstdc++6-4.4-dev_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb) 
Unpacking replacement libstdc++6-4.4-dev 
Setting up libstdc++6 (4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)`

Comment: `Setting up g++-4.4 (4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libstdc++6-4.4-dev (4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) ...
ocpe@blrkec241972d:~/Download/g++$ g++ -v
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
`

Comment: Check to see if `g++` is actually linked to this package. I'm running `g++` 4.7.1, so I think 4.4 might be linked to something like `g++-4.4`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be working in some cases, but I recently ran into the same issue in Linux Mint 13. the suggested commands (sudo dpkg -i ./.deb) will temporarily install such packages, however they will still be registered as "broken" (i.e. you are barred from using or even modifying your packages until these conflicts are resolved). The only way to resolve these is through a package manager. No other way is possible currently.

Funny thing, I discovered these nonsense dependencies when trying to replace the ethernet adapter's faulty driver with a working one. Turns out that most Linux distributions do not come with development tools (so you cannot just "make install" in an offline mode). But because there is no way to install packages offline due to sloppy developer policies [circular dependencies, self-dependencies, dpkg not working in these cases], some Linux version may come out as permanently broken on certain platforms (if internet connection does not work).

Suggestions? I would suggest spamming the developer forums to request strict dependency policies from programmers: no module should EVER be released to the public BEFORE an automatic dependency check has been run on it (to avoid self-dependencies, which is pretty lame). In case of circular dependencies (i.e. a depends on b, b depends on c, c depends on a), modules should be required be merged to a single one prior to release. Does not matter how big that file will become. There is nothing worse than a system which appears to be modular, but in fact the modules are making more problems than they ever solve. A non-modular "block" policy should be a MUST in this case.

The world out there is complicated... Only people make it even more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

i do:
sudo dpkg -i g++-4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb libstdc++6-4.4-dev_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb

prebious that i donnload the pacage in:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/g++-4.4/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libstdc++6-4.4-dev/download